# not able to make resource compiler to work with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++

I use C++ with Code::Blocks. I like Code::Block, but I can't make resource compiler get working... My test setup is very simple.

```
**in MoviesList.rc file:**

#include "MoviesList.h"

IDR_TEXT1  RCDATA "C:\\_C++\\PROJECTS\\test2\\MoviesList.txt"

**in MoviesList.h file:**

#define IDR_TEXT1 101

**in main()**
{
    HRSRC resInfo = ::FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_TEXT1), RT_RCDATA);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this compile error all the time:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe  -J rc -O coff -i C:\_C__~1\PROJECTS\test2\MOVIES~1.RC -o obj\Debug\MoviesList.res
Execution of 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe  -J rc -O coff -i C:\_C__~1\PROJECTS\test2\MOVIES~1.RC -o obj\Debug\MoviesList.res' in 'C:\_C++\PROJECTS\test2' failed.
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).
```

Compiler setup is the following:

```
C compiler:              x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
C++ compiler:            x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
Linker for dynamic libs: x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
Linker for static libs : x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar.exe
Resource compiler:       x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe
Make program:            mingw32-make.exe
```

When I go to project's Properties and then to  Build Targets I see that main.cpp and MoviesList.rc are checked, which should be correct...  I have Mingw version 4.8.1 and Code::Blocks version is 12.11. All things including Boost work fine, except for the resource compiler.

**UPDATE**

After changing from x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe to **windres.exe** the build has produce no errors.
There is no x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe in MinGW/bin, just windres.exe.... I

Entry for the resource compiler has been incorrect.

Comment: No additional diagnostics from the ressource compiler? I would start it from the command line.

Comment: @harper thanks! your suggestion made me think in the right direction ...

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks is an IDE that invokes the compiler, linker and other tools like the resource compiler. The output of these tools is catched and displayed in the output window.

When you don't get any output from one of these tools you should take the build log and start the tools with the parameter you found in the build log. This might help to isolate the problem.

Additionally you could change the parameters. e.g tell the compiler to stop after preprocessing to look at the preprocessed output. Similar options may exist for the resorce compiler.